# Multiple images upload failing in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: media-library

I have found an odd behavior of an uploading images into media library. Depends on a browser, I can select multiple files at the time or not. For example:

**It doesn't work in Chrome and in Firefox:**

[image: Chrome and Firefox - Multiple select is not available]

**It works fine in Opera:**

[image: Opera - Multiple select is available]

But it works fine in the Chrome browser on the machine of my colleague.

I thought that the reason is in Adobe Flash which isn't probably installed in my Chrome and is installed for Chrome of my colleague, but not, it isn't installed for both.

Maybe someone knows a reason of this behavior? I need to explain client why he can't select multiple files, but I don't have any idea and I can't recommend him to use Opera browser :).

Comment: yes is a adobe flash problem, to avoid this problem I remember you have to set Upload.Classic setting to true. Can you give a try ?

Comment: I guess if I set the Upload.Classic setting to true, the single file selection will always be shown. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @SitecoreClimber I tried and I was right. When I set true for Upload.Classic, I am always able to select just one file at the time. But on the contrary I need to have the opportunity to select several.

Comment: can you try on incogntito mode where you don't have extensions on your browser, do you have antivirus and your colleague not?

Comment: @SitecoreClimber We both don't have an antivirus. When I open sitecore in the incognito mode, the multiple file upload is available. Very strange.

Comment: can you delete cookies on normal mode and try again ?

Comment: @SitecoreClimber It helped. Do you now what it was? :)

Comment: I will add my answer . I guess sc_fv cookie it was the issue, it contains the flash version.

Comment: @ArtsemPrashkovich please reload images without client data visible

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I saw this behavior when you have a firewall, antivirus or cookies are corrupted.
Somehow
Please try to delete all your cookies and try again.

Cookie with key : **sc_fv** contains Flash Version and probably somehow this one was corrupted.
On the method Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.Media.MultiUpload.QueryState(CommandContext context) is verifying method **UseFlashUpload**

This method verify if your Sitecore Client SupportFlashUpload:

```
public virtual bool SupportsFlashUpload
{
    get
    {
        return this.GetFlashVersion().Major >= 9;
    }
}
```

on the method GetFlashVersion it reads sc_fv cookie value:

```
    protected virtual Version GetFlashVersion()
    {
    string cookieValue = WebUtil.GetCookieValue("sc_fv");
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cookieValue))
    {
        return new Version(0, 0, 0);
    }
    string[] array = cookieValue.Split(new char[]
    {
        '.'
    });
    if (array.Length != 3)
    {
        Log.Error("Unexpected flash version cookie value: " + cookieValue, this);
        return new Version(0, 0, 0);
    }
    int @int = MainUtil.GetInt(array[0], 0);
    int int2 = MainUtil.GetInt(array[1], 0);
    int int3 = MainUtil.GetInt(array[2], 0);
    return new Version(@int, int2, int3);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and explanation! You really saved my time. Grate job! 

Comment: Welcome, anytime.

Comment: Digging into how the uploader works (in 8.1 at least) it uses yui uploader which uses HTML5+XMLHttpRequest 2 or Flash as a fallback so if you don't have flash installed then it should work in most browsers:  https://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/uploader/

Comment: oh friends.. there's opportunity here. HTML5 File API replaces flash as the uploader of choice. Flash does cover older browsers that won't handle HTML5 (which are few honestly). Hmm.. I guess I'd have to know telerik better to make good use myself

Comment: I manually updated the cookie value to 9.0.0 and it started working.

Answer (score 4):

To add to this, Flash is indeed the culprit. If you're looking for something a little more perm. support recommends the following:

For the 'Upload File' dialog:

1. Navigate to `\Website\sitecore\shell\Applications\Media\Upload Media\`
2. Open the `UploadMedia.xml` file
3. On line **27**, add the attribute `multiple="true"` to the `<input id="File" ... />` tag:
   `<input id="File" name="File" type="file" style="width:100%" multiple="true"/>`

For the "Upload files (advanced)" dialog:

1. Navigate to the `\Website\sitecore\shell\Applications\Media\UploadManager` folder
2. Open `Upload.aspx`
3. Find the `<input id="File0" name="File0" .../>` tag inside the file and add the `multiple="true"` attribute:
   `<input multiple="true" id="File0" name="File0" type="file" value="browse" onchange="javascript:return Sitecore.Upload.change(this)"/>`
4. Open the `Upload.aspx.js` file
5. Search for `ctl.type = "file";` line and put a new line after it:
   `ctl.multiple = true;`

*Please note that this workaround has not passed full QA cycle. In case of any issue with upload please revert the changes.*

Answer (score 0):

The problem stems from the cookie sc_fv resetting to the value of 0.0.0 upon browser restart.  The best workaround I found was using a browser extension such as edit this cookie to lock the value of the cookie to 31.0.0

[image: Edit This Cookie sc_fv]